# Calling a method from one class to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In PilotRaceLap model class I am trying to call a method from another class but keep getting `NoMethodError`.

```
class PilotRaceLap < ActiveRecord::Base
 acts_as_paranoid
  belongs_to :race_session

 def mark_splitted
  prl = RaceSessionAdapter.track_lap_time(pilot.transponder_token,lap_time/2) <<<ERROR HERE
 end
```

track_lap_time is declared in this adapter class:

```
class RaceSessionAdapter
 attr_accessor :race_session

def track_lap_time(transponder_token,delta_time_in_ms)
 ...
end
```

race_session model class starts like that:

```
class RaceSession < ActiveRecord::Base
 acts_as_paranoid

 has_many :pilot_race_laps
 has_many :race_attendees
```

Comment: `def self.track_lap_time`, without self you're declaring an instance method but since you need to use it as a class method self should be added

Comment: Since i am editing a git project i assume track_lap_time is already used in the code. Isn't there any other way to reach the method without changing the method itself?

Comment: `RaceSessionAdapter.new.track_lap_time`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RaceSessionAdapter.new.track_lap_time()`

Answer (score 1):

track_lap_time should be a class method (it's instance method right now). Just add `self.` before name.

```
def self.track_lap_time()
  ...
end
```

or write this method in `class << self` block

```
class << self
  def track_lap_time()
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: This will require to change most of the code since it is already in use in a working app

Comment: If you don't want to change most of your code then you can leave `track_lap_time` instance method with this implementation: `def track_lap_time(*args); self.class.track_lap_time(*args); end; def self.track_lap_time(transponder_token, delta_time_in_ms); ...; end`